# Autofocus on multi-select drop down list if nothing is selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a multi-select drop-down list defined as such:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Members, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple", autofocus = "autofocus"})
```

Note that Members is defined as such:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a member")]
    public List<int> Members { get; set; }
```

When the user fills out the form and clicks on submit, if nothing is selected for the the multi-select drop down list, it does not set focus on element.

Note that I am using an ajax call to dynamically fill in the name, value pair for the drop down list.

Comment: Make sure that your form view containing `@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}` this and let me know the effect.

Comment: Does it auto-select-on-error for other controls?  Eg a simple `@Html.TexboxFor(m=>m.TextField)`

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes it works for textboxfor but just not for this multi-select drop down.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I tried but did not have any affect.

Comment: I didn't found any problems when tried to reproduce in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dkjqyc). Probably the problem is not in the `autofocus` setting but the `RequiredAttribute` itself?